# Uncheck all mat angular check boxes in a mat angular table without adding any new column into the data set

Tags: angular

I'm working on Angular-6 and Mat Angular components. I have added check boxes for all rows of the table, now I want to reset all the check boxes on certain events.

Example: When the page loads all the check boxes will be unchecked and I'm checking few of the check boxes and once I'm clicking on the header check box then all other check box should check/un-check.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/uncheckall?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

NOTE: Already did some searching but all solution suggesting creating another array which I want to avoid as I can't modify the data coming from server and don't want increase size of data unnecessarily.

***If you don't understand the question let me know to clarify it before downgrading the question.***

Comment: Your checkboxes aren't bound to anything. Start doing that, and then change the model value they're bound to, and that will uncheck them. You need to learn how to use forms in Angular. Currently, your checkbowes are useless anyway, since you have no way to know if they're checked or not, and do nothing with them.

Comment: In-case of model I think you are suggesting to create an array for all the check boxes in the row..  Can we use dom selector or some other method to achieve the same instead of creating an array for all check-boxes?

Comment: The whole idea of angular is to avoid doing DOM manipulation and instead bind the DOM elements to a model in your code, and use that model. If you're into DOM manipulation, you should use jQuery, not Angular. Add a boolean `checked` to PeriodicElement, and bind the checkbox to that boolean. that way, you'll know if a PeriodicElement is checked or not. And setting it's checked property to false will uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: @JBNizet, I got your suggestion,now it's working.. thanks a lot

Comment: Have you looked at `SelectionModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Aim

You are looking for check and uncheck boxes without copying the existing data `ELEMENT_DATA`.

> ### Solution

To perform check and un-check for multiple checkbox, its necessary to have the bind of all the checkbox.So we need one more variable `checkboxStates` which will contains only the checkbox states not the entire copied data. This way we can avoid the extra memory consumption and it will keep your original data intact.

### Steps 1

Create the variable to hold the checkbox state

```
checkboxStates = {}
```

### Step 2

Create the default states for all checkboxes

```
  constructor() {
    ELEMENT_DATA.forEach(item => {
      this.checkboxStates[item.position] = false
    });
  }
```

### Step 3

Check and Uncheck operation

```
changeCheckBoxesStatus(e: MatCheckboxChange) {
    console.log(e.checked)
    if (e.checked) {
      Object.keys(this.checkboxStates).forEach(key => {
        this.checkboxStates[key] = true;
      })
    } else {
      Object.keys(this.checkboxStates).forEach(key => {
        this.checkboxStates[key] = false;
      })
    }
  }
```

### Step 4

Bind the checkbox model

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkboxStates[element.position]" ></mat-checkbox>
```

Here is working copy - https://stackblitz.com/edit/uncheckall-yhvaw5

Comment: I got your solution.. but what if we create a model and add the model in [checked] atrribute of all the child check boxes.. in this case we don't have to maintain another object for it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/uncheckall?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is also doable but maintaining the separate array of all models will require additional precaution because it might create duplicate model in checkbox specially when addition of new Model is happening in multiple places.